# How do you manipulate the third argument of the range function to go up a factor of n?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python's for loop accepts three arguments in the range of the for loop. How could I manipulate the third argument to be a factor?

```
factor_of = 2
li = []
for i in range(first_value, 25000, factor_of):
    li.append(i)
```

Now I realize this will go up 2 every time, but how would I make it to where the first value is going to be multiplied by `factor_of` each time and that is stored in the `i` value?

The desired affect would be (assuming `first_value` is set to `10`)

```
[10, 20, 40, 80, 160, ...]
```

And yes, I know this makes more sense in a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `while` loop as suggested by @Delgan. Nevertheless, if you still prefer to employ a `for` loop, here's the solution I came up with<sup>*</sup>:

```
from math import log, ceil

def my_func(first, last, factor):
    x = log(last/first)/log(factor)
    n = int(x + 1 if x - int(x) == 0 else ceil(x))
    return [first*factor**i for i in range(n)]
```

`my_func` returns the desired list. The `i`th element of the list comprehension is computed as `first*factor**i`, where the index `i` varies from `0` to `n - 1`, being `n` the smallest integer number that satisfies:

```
first * factor**n >= last
```

Demo:

```
In [331]: my_func(10, 2500, 2)
Out[331]: [10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280]

In [332]: my_func(10, 10000, 10)
Out[332]: [10, 100, 1000, 10000]

In [333]: my_func(2, 8000, 5)
Out[333]: [2, 10, 50, 250, 1250, 6250]
```

As a final note it is worth pointing out that this approach could be affected by the round off errors associated to floating point arithmetic.

<sup>*</sup> I'm assuming you use Python 3. To get the code working in Python 2 an additional `import` sentence is needed to avoid integer division errors: `from __future__ import division`

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do such a thing using the built-in [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range). However, you can define your own [generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/), like this:

```
def range_factor(start, stop, factor_of):
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start *= factor_of

li = list(range_factor(10, 25000, 2))
# [10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280, 2560, 5120, 10240, 20480]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
factor_of = 2
for i in range(1,15):
    print( 10 * factor_of**i )
```

or:

```
[ 10*factor_of**i for i in range(1,15) ]
```